# pyCallGraph windows 7, python 3.6 no admin

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to profile my code for the first time using pyCallGraph.
I am on Windows 7, Python 3.6

I have used

```
pip install pyCallGraph
pip install graphviz
```

Which completed successfully.
Now when I try to use the commands in a python script I get the following error :

```
PyCallGraphException: The command "dot" is required to be in your path.
```

So ok I know that something is not in my "path" whatever that is. I cannot use the traditional answer given (i.e. go to windows, properties, advanced, ...) because I don't have the admin rights on my computer.

So I guess there is a way to add something to the "path" using a script but since I don't know what "path" is it is difficult for me to get the right commands.

I have tried :

```
old_path = os.environ['PATH']
os.environ['PATH'] = "{}{}{}".format(path, os.pathsep, old_path)
old_path = os.environ['PATH']
```

where

```
path = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\graphviz')
```

but this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Installing the graphviz python package won't install `dot` - you need to install the actual Graphviz software from https://graphviz.org/.